# Seeking global data for georeferenced CO2 emissions of industrial sites

Tags: data-request, global, industry

I am looking for georeferenced CO2 emissions of sites of energy-intensive industry sectors on a global scale. Besides the EU-ETS and the E-PRTR, I found the [Hotmaps projects](https://www.hotmaps-project.eu/) covering EU28, but no project covering the global scale.

Does anyone know of such a project?

If such a comprehensive overview of energy-intensive industry sectors on a global scale is not available, I would also be interested in open-source sectoral databases covering the global scale.

During my research I came across the following data sources:

- [GIDmodel database](http://gidmodel.org.cn/) covering the cement, iron and steel industry
- [RISI Pulp and Paper database](https://www.risiinfo.com/product/asset-database/) covering the pulp and paper industry, which is not available for free
- [GlassGlobal database](https://plants.glassglobal.com/login/) covering the glass industry, which is not available for free